# Hide text without html tag parent being hide jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a text inside the html tag, the problem inside this html tag the text not wrapped inside any tag, so it makes me wonder how to hide the text. here's my code:

```
<ul class="nav items"> 
   <li class="nav item ">
      <strong>
        <i class="ion-speedometer"></i> Dashboard
      </strong>
   </li>
   <li class="nav item"><a href="#"><i class="ion-model-s"> </i>Delivery Order History</a></li>
   <li class="nav item vendor-guide  ">
      <a href="#"><i class="ion-help"> </i>Help Guide</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav item" id="collapse-list">
      <div class="seperator">
         <span class="outer-line"></span>
         <span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left" id="arrow-collapse" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0"></span>
         <span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right" id="arrow-show" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0;display:none;"></span>
         <span class="outer-line"></span>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see from above code beneath `li` html tag there is a text html tag container which is `strong` or `a`,  beside text there is an icon. here's my jQuery code:

```
$('#arrow-collapse').click(function() {
    //hide the text
 });
$('#arrow-show').click(function() {
    //show the text
});
```

Comment: So do you want to hide the whole body?

Comment: You can't, without a tag, there is nothing to 'apply' the `hide` style/css to.

Comment: @ParagJadhav no i just want to hide the text

Comment: Hide all words and leave icons?

Comment: I guess you could use a data attribute on the `<a>` tag to store the original text, and a data attribute to store the status of the text, either visible or hidden. Then on click you either remove the text or add it. I would advise against it and just add a <span> around the text.

Answer (score 1):

The `display` and `visibility` attributes targets the content/children within that HTML tag. There is no way to hide just the text inside a tag, and not the other children as well. You could attempt to "hide" the text by doing `text-indent: -999999px;` to move the text outside what is visible, and then adjust the position for the other children tags.

Your other option here is to wrap the text in a tag, for example `span` and hide that.

Minimal example*:

```css
div {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
div strong,
div i {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Outside text
<strong>strong text</strong>
<i>Itallic text</i>
</div>
```

Note that this approach will not work unless you have `display: block;` on the `strong` and `i` tags, as these are inline by default. `text-indent` does not work on inline elements.

Comment: yes, i want to be able move out the text and move in the text again, can you provide the working code?

Comment: @ShellSuite Provided a minimal example.

Comment: @ShellSuite OptimusCrime (cool name) is giving you options. If you can live with wrapping the text then it's not that hard to do. Just let us know if you can deal with a wrapper or not. There is one more option to hide and show text without a wrapper though, I still don't get what text you want to hide?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#arrow-collapse').click(function() {
   $('#arrow-collapse').text("");
});
$('#arrow-show').click(function() {
   $('#arrow-show').text("Text");
});
```

or

```
<span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left" id="arrow-collapse" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0">
   <span class="collapse-text">Collapse Text</span>
</span>
<span class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right" id="arrow-show" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:10px 0;display:none;">
   <span class="show-text">Show Text</span>
</span>
```

Then

```
$('#arrow-collapse').click(function() {
   $('.collapse-text').show(); //for example
});
$('#arrow-show').click(function() {
   $('.show-text').show(); //for example
});
```